# error when installing package tables for python

Tags: python, installation, package

This is the problem when I try to build package tables-3.1.1 for python:

```
sudo python setup.py build_ext --inplace
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
* Using Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
* Found numpy 1.6.1 package installed.
* Found numexpr 2.4 package installed.
* Found Cython 0.20.2 package installed.
* Found HDF5 headers at ``/usr/local/include``, library at ``/usr/local/lib``.
* Found LZO 2 headers at ``/usr/local/include``, library at ``/usr/local/lib``.
* Skipping detection of LZO 1 since LZO 2 has already been found.
* Found bzip2 headers at ``/usr/local/include``, library at ``/usr/lib``.
/tmp/blosc_list_compressors0xPbk3.c:1:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main (int argc, char **argv) {
^~~~
/tmp/blosc_list_compressors0xPbk3.c:2:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'blosc_list_compressors' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    blosc_list_compressors();
    ^
2 warnings generated.
ld: library not found for -lblosc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: library not found for -lblosc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
* Could not find blosc headers and library; using internal sources.
Setting compiler flag '-msse2'
running build_ext
```

I understand that it couldn't find blosc library. I tried to import blosc in python:

```
>>> import blosc
>>> help(blosc)

        ------
        TypeError
            If packed_array is not of type bytes or string.

        Examples
        --------

        >>> import numpy
        >>> a = numpy.arange(1e6)
        >>> parray = blosc.pack_array(a)
        >>> len(parray) < a.size*a.itemsize
        True
        >>> a2 = blosc.unpack_array(parray)
        >>> numpy.alltrue(a == a2)
        True

DATA
    __all__ = ['compress', 'compress_ptr', 'decompress', 'decompress_ptr',...
    __version__ = '1.2.4'

VERSION
    1.2.4
```

So, python can find blosc package. Can someone help me to solve the problem in installing package tables, please?
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the blosc development libraries. If you're running either CentOS or Fedora, try `sudo yum install blosc-devel`. For Ubuntu, I could not find a similar package, which means you will likely have to build from source. [There are tarballs here](https://github.com/Blosc/c-blosc/releases), and you will have to follow [their build instructions](https://github.com/Blosc/c-blosc/blob/master/README.rst).

Comment: I'm working on Mac OS X 10.8. It gave `command not found` for yum. I tried pip instead, it responded `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement blosc-devel`. Searching on Google didn't give me any result for `blosc-devel`.

Comment: @ anders: according to your advice, I installed bcolz then installed tables again successfully. However, `import tables` gives error `ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so, 2): Symbol not found: _H5E_CALLBACK_g`. I look at the installing description and see warnings: `Could not find the HDF5 runtime.The HDF5 shared library was *not* found in the default library paths.` `Could not find the LZO 2 runtime. The LZO 2 shared library was *not* found in the default library paths.` `ld: library not found for -lblosc. * Could not find blosc headers and library`

Comment: When you encounter a problem like this, Google is your friend. What the build command is telling you is that it has dependencies that are not met. In thi case, it looks like HDF5 and LZ0 2. I searched for "HDF5 os x" and found [this link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/23144#issuecomment-25945969). Try those commands to install via homebrew.

Comment: For LZO 2, [here are some instructions](http://vertascale.com/blog-events/blog/installing-lzo-on-your-mac/). Again, all I did was google "LZO 2 os x". You may encounter some issues related to paths, and there's a [solution/workaround here](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/219) (look at the call to `python setup.py` and how he manually specifies the library locations).